# Can't connect to the MySql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connect to MySQL server, but appear errors I can't handle.

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:902)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>           at Main.main(Main.java:21)
>       Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'chechevica'@'%' to database 'peoples'
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>           at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:129)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:810)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:735)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:703)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:132)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:557)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:220)
>           at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1443)
>           at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:846)
>           ... 7 more
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at Main.main(Main.java:39)

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    // JDBC URL, username and password of MySQL server
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    private static final String user = "chechevica";
    private static final String password = "**ur_SQLparol**";

    // JDBC variables for opening and managing connection
    private static Connection connection;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static ResultSet resultSet;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "SELECT id_user FROM users";

        try {
            // opening database connection to MySQL server
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            // getting Statement object to execute query
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // executing SELECT query
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Total number of users in the table : " + count);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //close connection ,stmt and resultSet here
            try { connection.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
            try { statement.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
            try { resultSet.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you phpmyadmin?

Comment: No, I haven't, why?

Comment: Or any mysql management tool

Comment: MySQL 8.0 that's what i have

Comment: This is the version of the MySQL server. I meant a tool that let you navigate through DB, tables, etc... How did you build your database and tables?

Comment: I was doing it using MySQL Command Line Client.

Comment: Log in using `mysql --user=chechevica --password peoples`

Comment: I've already logged in as a user 'chechevica', but my password isn't 'peoples'.

Comment: I know, this is the database name you've tried to use.

Comment: there r no peoples, what am i gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

Root cause here is that user **chechevica** has no access to **peoples** DB:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'chechevica'@'%' to database 'peoples' at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at
```

You just need to grant access to this user to resolve your issue, something like this will work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON peoples.* TO 'chechevica'@'%';
```

For additional details about granting in MySQL it will be useful to read [this >>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)